# Is it possible to compute the y-coordinate of a point on SECP256K1, given only the x-coordinate

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves

Given an x-coordiante of a point on the SECP256K1 curve, is it possible to calculate the corresponding y-coorindate? (Assuming the point is a verifying public key that complies with the Bitcoin standards.)

I am new to the cryptographic realm so please forgive me if the question is naive. From what I know, the public key is a point, or a pair of integers. The SECP256K1 curve is a curve where any point `(x, y)` on it satisfies

```
(y ** 2) mod p == (x ** 3 + 7) mod p
```

where `p = 2**256 - 2**32 - 977`.

Now let's confine the discussion within the Bitcoin scope. Assume we have a private key that complies with the Bitcoin standards, and from it we can derive the public key, which can be represented as a point `(x, y)` on the SECP256K1 curve.

Now given only such a `x`, is it possible to calculate the `y`?

As a real example, given only `x` as

```
0x6778ec0abf66f1ba4d93aa45cad77dc26c593f520448f6fff5b70357270154ba
```

is it possible get the `y` as

```
0x6a5e8cd7276f80ee2f7c081702eff3e14134b006acd0afc8467be94a0a3a0558
```

Comment: SEC#1 from http://secg.org explains it in section 2.3.4. Octet-String-to-Elliptic-Curve-Point Conversion.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right direction. The key part is an efficient algorithm to compute the modular square root, namely the Tonelli–Shanks algorithm, which I didn't know and I was asking for, and which I know now. If time permits I can make an answer my own.

Comment: Note that the linked strategy requires an extra byte (or rather 2 bit) of information as there are two possible $y$ values for each $x$.

Comment: In the compression form, the value of $g$ starts with `02` or `03`, '02' tells to select the root whose least significant bit is even, and versa.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that makes it one bit instead of two, although in this case it is encoded into two bits (`02` and `03` in hex where the most significant bit is undoubtedly set to indicate that compression is being used, and the least significant bit encodes even / odd).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: 01 is not used; 00 is infinity aka $O$ and 04 is uncompressed. X9.62 used 06 and 07 for hybrid, but SEC1 and AFAIK everybody else just ignored hybrid as being silly and useless.

Comment: Note that, Andreas's book is not a good source to learn elliptic curves, since they use [_EC multiplication instead of EC scalar multiplication](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/96056/18298)_ that confused many [How do I multiply two points on an elliptic curve?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88214/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka oh my, thank you for finding that thread, I have been searching this question on even google and this platform but didn't find that result somehow

Comment: May you suggest to me some books about cryptography in general, or about bitcoin/blockchain specifically? I am totally new to this topic and this book was what Google had recommended me.

Comment: You should accept the dupe when see it, this is the way of our site. It is good on the non-math side. The math side really depends on you.  If you need Hash functions, Elliptic Curves, Digital signatures like ECDSA, I suggest Serious Cryptography: A Practical Introduction to Modern Encryption

Comment: Another good cryptography book is Katz and Lindell's "Introduction to Modern Cryptography", and for bitcoin maybe "Grokking Bitcoin" by Rosenbaum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Given an $x$-coordinate of a point on the SECP256K1 curve, is it possible to calculate the corresponding $y$-coordinate?

Yes, if there exists such $y$ for the given $x$. And, absent other indication, such $y$ can only be found within sign (or equivalently, parity). That limitation is because if $y^2\equiv x^3+7\pmod p$ with $p=2^{256}−2^{32}−2^{10}+2^6-2^4−1$ as in `secp256k1` has a solution $y_0$ in $[0,p)$, then $y_1=p-y_0$ also is a solution.

Note: in some cases including `secp256k1` as used in Bitcoin, a public key with $x$ and without $y$ (that is, in compressed form) comes with a prefix of `02` if $y$ is even, `03` if $y$ is odd, and that allows to fully recover $y$.

By [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion), $x^3+7$ has a square root modulo $p$ if and only if $(x^3+7)^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p=1$. That holds for the question's $x$, thus there are solutions.

In the general case, the [Tonelli–Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) can be used to find modular square roots. Since $p\equiv3\pmod4$, that algorithm reduces to computing $y_0\gets (x^3+7)^{(p+1)/4}\bmod p$ and $y_1\gets p-y_0$. The question's $y$ happens to be $y_1$.

Justification: when we have checked $(x^3+7)^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p=1$, and computed $y_0$ as $(x^3+7)^{(p+1)/4}\bmod p$, the later is such that $$\begin{array}{}
{y_0}^2 &\equiv&\left((x^3+7)^{(p+1)/4}\right)^2 &\pmod p \\
& \equiv&(x^3+7)^{(p+1)/2} &\pmod p \\
&\equiv&(x^3+7)^{(p-1)/2}\,(x^3+7)&\pmod p\\
&\equiv&x^3+7 &\pmod p & \text{since}\;(x^3+7)^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p=1\end{array}$$
thus $y_0$ is a solution to $y^2\equiv x^3+7\pmod p$.

---

Definitions:
$$\begin{array}{l}
u\equiv v\pmod p&\underset{\text{def}}\iff v-u\;\text{ is a multiple of }\;p\\
u=v\bmod p&\underset{\text{def}}\iff v-u\;\text{ is a multiple of }\;p\;\text{ and }0\le u<p\;
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 8):

The curve used by bitcoin is secp256k1, which has the equation
$$y^2 = x^3 + 7$$

That means every single point $P = (x, y)$ on the curve must satisfy this equation.

So, given $x$, we can compute the right hand side of the equation $x^3 + 7$ to obtain $y^2$. Then we need to "square root" this in the field $F_p$ to find $y$. Note that is *not* the same as taking the square root of a real number.

We shall require that $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, which is true of the prime $p$ ($= 2^{256} - 2^{32} - 977$) which is used in secp256k1. The way to compute this "square root" of an element $a$ in $F_p$, when $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, is to use the equation:
$$y = a^{(p+1)/4} \pmod{p}$$

You can check that this is true because suppose $a = y^2$. then
$$\left( a^{(p+1)/4} \right)^2 \equiv a^{(p+1)/2} \equiv y^{p+1} \pmod{p}$$
and then, by Fermat's little theorem:
$$y^{p+1}  \equiv y^2 \equiv a \pmod{p}$$

Your example is not great, because $10^3 + 7 \equiv 0 \pmod{19}$. So $y = 0$ is a trivial square root.

Using a different example, let's work over $F_{23}$, with $p = 23$, and keep the same value of $x = 10$. Then $10^3 + 7 \equiv 18 \pmod{23}$. Now, to compute $y$ such that $y^2 \equiv 18 \pmod{23}$, we use the above equation:
$$y = 18^{(23+1)/4} = 18^6 \equiv 8 \pmod{23}$$

To confirm this, we can check that $8^2$ does indeed equal $18$ modulo 23. So the point we are looking for is $(10, 8)$. Note too that there is the "negative" version of the point with the same x-coordinate, $(10, -8) \equiv (10, 15)$, because $y^2 = (-y)^2$. We can check this too, because $15^2 \equiv 18 \pmod{23}$ as expected.

Note that not all $x$ values will have a valid corresponding $y$ value. We expect roughly half the possible choices of $x$ to correspond to (usually) two points each. When $a = x^3 + 7$ does indeed have a corresponding $y$ value such that $y^2 = a$, then we say a is a *quadratic residue* modulo $p$.

Comment: Thank you really much for your detailed explanation, I have been doing searches about this at got stuck at the part everyone mentioned about the condition p mod 4 = 3. I am curious about how that requirement came up in the first place? Like to make the function easier to solve or something similar?

Comment: Yep, it makes it a lot easier. In the general case, we need to use the [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) algorithm. It is still doable, of course, just a bit more complicated.