# Elliptic Curve how to calculate y value

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, prime-numbers, number-theory, elliptic-curve-generation

I have been reading the book Mastering Bitcoin written by Andreas. It was the process of compressing public keys that hurt my mind. Specifically, a public key after being generated from a private key fundamentally comprises the resulting coordination of x and y.

The book said that since y value can be gained from x via the function: $$y^2\bmod p=(x^3 + 7)\bmod p$$We can reduce the size by just storing the x with the sign value.

While I understood how point addition in Elliptic Curve works, I could not understand how to find y given an x and p value? For example: $y^2 \bmod p = (10^3 + 7) \bmod 19$

Thank you very much in advance, this is a very new topic to me and hopefully I can learn more from you guys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to compute the y-coordinate of a point on SECP256K1, given only the x-coordinate](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/82027/is-it-possible-to-compute-the-y-coordinate-of-a-point-on-secp256k1-given-only-t) Just a little search and found it since I remember such question.